# Make Cards responding to presses or taps in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

One thing I have noticied is that the lists seem to be automatically 'selectable' and upon touching it will open a detail view of whatever that list item is.

I have been trying to do the same thing with Cards but have had no luck. Has anyone else here done it?

Comment: SHould I build my own cards?

Answer (score 1):

you can use list card with `<a>` tag to enable detail view and link to other page

```
<div class="list card">

  <a href="#view/{{id}}" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
    Enter home address
  </a>

  <a href="#view/{{}}" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
    Phone Card
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-wifi"></i>
    Wireless Card
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-card"></i>
    Card Info
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. You need to change the hrefs to point to your desired pages. You can use [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#ui-sref) to make it easy on yourself.

Comment: ahh the frusterating thing is it seems to be pointing to the right page, but will nto switch page